# How do I open an HTML file in Python

Tags: python, html

I've tried various different ways to open an HTML file from python code, but each time I get a '500 internal server error'.

Here is my python script:

```
    if (variable == "0, User and IP logged"): #conditional to check if user's credentials were accepted by the API
        page = urllib.urlopen("mainPage.html").read()
        print page
        #html file is opened and read - NOT WORKING!
```

Here is my html file:

```
    <html>
    <header><title>This is title</title></header>
    <body>
    Hello world
    </body>
    </html>
```

How do I get the python script to display my hello world page?
My tutor said I should use open(), but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Are you trying to open a local file? If so just use `open`. Also you may be able to make your project neater using a library like `flask` which supports templating using `jinja` library.

Comment: urllib.url(open) is used to open url connection not html page .If you want to start a site you must use 'flask' 'bottle' kind of modules.To just read the mainPage.html you can just use file read option

Comment: I second @PaulRooney's suggestion of `flask` and `jinja2`. (Although I would insist on `jinja2` over `jinja`. ;) The original `jinja` was last updated in 2008!) If you don't need the web framework provided by `flask`, the `jinja2` templating engine may still be useful. The benefits of a templating engine are significant.

Comment: @jpmc26 of course. I wasn't actually being specific about a version, but yes jinja2 is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to run Web Server which will server web pages :

Here I am using sample bottle web framework

**bottle_server.py**

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def dashboard():
    return '<b>This is index page</b>'

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Run script using

> python bottle_server.py

Now, Server is running on localhost on port 8080

Here is sample python script

**Client.py**

```
import urllib
print urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:8080/").read()
```

Run client script using

> python Client.py

This will produce output like

```
<b>This is index page</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab('helloworld.html')
```